# Click on a chart and open the same chart in another window with MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, livecharts

I have a Window in XAML with some different charts. What I wanted to do is to click that chart and open another window that shows me the same chart and another elements added to the GUI, but I don´t know what I am looking to, I am not sure if MVVM would help me or shoukd I start looking for something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [input bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputbinding?view=netframework-4.8):

```
<ChartPart Background="Transparent">
  <ChartPart.InputBindings>


    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ShowInAntoherView}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding Path}"
                  Gesture="LeftDoubleClick""/>

  </ChartPart.InputBindings>
```

(Background=Transparent is important, because if the background is null, control does not pass a check if it was clicked)

This allows you invoke commands with parameters on pretty much all controls on a variety of possible user actions.

Just pass a clicked chart viewModel to a command that will navigate to it - done.

What a `<ChartPart>` is in your case depends on a library you use (in your case it is Livecharts), but it should not be a problem to figure out.

Comment: perfect thank you! Okay let´s say I have clicked my chart and it opens the other window, then I make some changes in my chart (second window) and finally I want to see the changes in the first window. I know I need to add the corresponding code, but for the XAML could it work like this?

Comment: If you want to be able to cancel the changes, you need to edit a copy of the data in the other window. Then, when user clicks `Save` or `OK`, you passed edited version back to the first window and replace the old data. Bindings should refresh the chart (if you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` setup correctly)

Comment: In XAML all you do is to bind the click/double click user action to a command. Everything else is done in ViewModels code

Comment: Thank you, but there is something I have not fully understand. If I have my chart in my View and I double click on it, it will open another window with the same chart. But in this case, on this window I can move the points of my chart. So that means, I need to Views right? I was thinking of just adding to my First Window a <local:SecondWindow/> and here add what you just told me or should I like completley use the same chart for the two windows, I mean literally copy and paste

Comment: There is [a way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1) to open new window and disable the old one at the same time. Also, from UX standpoint, you should allow the user to cancel or undo the changes, so displaying a copy of the chart in new window would be my choice